# Finding the index of a permutation within a string

Tags: java

I just attempted a programming challenge, which I was not able to successfully complete. The specification is to read 2 lines of input from `System.in`.

1. A list of 1-100 space separated words, all of the same length and between 1-10 characters.
2. A string up to a million characters in length, which contains a permutation of the above list just once. Return the index of where this permutation begins in the string.

For example, we may have:

```
dog cat rat
abcratdogcattgh
3
```

Where `3` is the result (as printed by `System.out`).

It's legal to have a duplicated word in the list:

```
dog cat rat cat
abccatratdogzzzzdogcatratcat
16
```

The code that I produced worked providing that the word that the answer begins with has not occurred previously. In the 2nd example here, my code will fail because `dog` has already appeared before where the answer begins at index 16.

My theory was to:

1. Find the index where each word occurs in the string
2. Extract this substring (as we have a number of known words with a known length, this is possible)
3. Check that all of the words occur in the substring
4. If they do, return the index that this substring occurs in the original string

Here is my code (it should be compilable):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] l = line.split(" ");
        String s = br.readLine();

        int wl = l[0].length();
        int len = wl * l.length;
        int sl = s.length();

        for (String word : l) {
            int i = s.indexOf(word);
            int z = i;
            //while (i != -1) {
                int y = i + len;
                if (y <= sl) {
                    String sub = s.substring(i, y);
                    if (containsAllWords(l, sub)) {
                        System.out.println(s.indexOf(sub));
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                //z+= wl;
                //i = s.indexOf(word, z);
            //}
        }
        System.out.println("-1");
    }

    private static boolean containsAllWords(String[] l, String s) {
        String s2 = s;

        for (String word : l) {
            s2 = s2.replaceFirst(word, "");
        }

        if (s2.equals(""))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am able to solve my issue and make it pass the 2nd example by un-commenting the `while` loop. However this has serious performance implications. When we have an input of 100 words at 10 characters each and a string of 1000000 characters, the time taken to complete is just awful.

Given that each case in the test bench has a maximum execution time, the addition of the while loop would cause the test to fail on the basis of not completing the execution in time.

What would be a better way to approach and solve this problem? I feel defeated.

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate the strings together and use the new string to search with.

```
String a = "dog"
String b = "cat"
String c = a+b; //output of c would be "dogcat"
```

Like this you would overcome the problem of dog appearing somewhere.

But this wouldn't work if catdog is a valid value too.

Comment: Since any permutation will do, this won't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach (pseudo code)

```
stringArray keys(n) = {"cat", "dog", "rat", "roo", ...};
string bigString(1000000);
L = strlen(keys[0]); // since all are same length
int indices(n, 1000000/L); // much too big - but safe if only one word repeated over and over

for each s in keys
  f = -1
  do:
    f = find s in bigString starting at f+1  // use bigString.indexOf(s, f+1)
    write index of f to indices
    until no more found
```

When you are all done, you will have a series of indices (location of first letter of match). Now comes the tricky part. Since the words are all the same length, we're looking for a sequence of indices that are all spaced the same way, in the 10 different "collections". This is a little bit tedious but it should complete in a finite time. Note that it's faster to do it this way than to keep comparing strings (comparing numbers is faster than making sure a complete string is matched, obviously). I would again break it into two parts - first find "any sequence of 10 matches", then "see if this is a unique permutation".

```
sIndx = sort(indices(:))
dsIndx = diff(sIndx);
sequence = find {n} * 10 in dsIndx
for each s in sequence
  check if unique permutation
```

I hope this gets you going.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best optimized version, but how about following theory to give you some ideas:

1. Count length of all words in row.
2. Take random word from list and find the starting index of its first
   occurence.
3. Take a substring with length counted above before and after that
   index (e.g. if index is 15 and 3 words of 4 letters long, take
   substring from 15-8 to 15+11).
4. Make a copy of the word list with earlier random word removed.
5. Check the appending/prepending [word_length] letters to see if they
   match a new word on the list.
6. If word matches copy of list, remove it from copy of list and move further
7. If all words found, break loop.
8. If not all words found, find starting index of next occurence of
   earlier random word and go back to 3.

Why it would help:

- Which word you pick to begin with wouldn't matter, since every word
  needs to be in the succcessful match anyway.
- You don't have to manually loop through a lot of the characters,
  unless there are lots of near complete false matches.
- As a supposed match keeps growing, you have less words on the list copy left to compare to.
- Can also keep track or furthest index you've gone to, so you can
  sometimes limit the backwards length of picked substring (as it
  cannot overlap to where you've already been, if the occurence are
  closeby to each other).